# Multiple fragments with same sensor

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sensors

I am writing a 'dash-board' application which includes several instruments based on the barometric sensor (for phones where this is available) and instruments using the position. The instruments are implemented as fragments.

The question is if it is best practice to manage the sensor-interface in the host activity, register the host activity as sensor event listener, and call the fragments methods with the  sensor event, or to interface the SystemService and register listeners etc. through each fragment individually?

My main concern is battery consumption and possible 'collisions' with fragments blocking each other while accessing the same resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is if it is best practice to manage the sensor-interface in the host activity, register the host activity as sensor event listener, and call the fragments methods with the sensor event, or to interface the SystemService and register listeners etc. through each fragment individually?

For things that transcend the bounds of a single fragment, having the activity handle it is certainly reasonable.

> My main concern is battery consumption

This shouldn't be a problem -- it's not like multiple sensors will be powered on because there are two with registered interest in the barometer. Heck, for all you know, there are other apps also using the barometer.

> and possible 'collisions' with fragments blocking each other while accessing the same resource

That too won't be a problem, any more than any other main application thread contention.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! So it seems like more a matter of coding style?
Regarding battery consumption, I assumed that having two fragments using e.g. the gps could force twice as many 'position requests' and hence greater gps on-time?

Comment: @Paamand: Well, in Android terminology, GPS isn't a "sensor" -- that term is reserved for things like the accelerometer. That being said, either the GPS radio is powered on, or it is not, and that's where the battery consumption comes from. Two fragments running simultaneously will not change that.

Comment: When you register to listen for location updates, you can request a long time period, which the LocationManager can use to decide to sleep based off of. So theoretically, if the second user of the GPS specified a smaller amount, it could keep the hardware powered up more often. I haven't looked at the code in many Android versions, but it used to be that listeners that requested more infrequent updates actually got as many as the most often update period requested. So the manager is smart enough to use the most often of all update periods it is given.